# Write Inno Setup environmental variable (srcexe) to a file

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to write the `srcexe` (Should return `c:\setup.exe`) to a file in my application folder.

Here is what I have tried. However the file gets created but it is empty.

Maybe im running in the wrong procedure or I'm calling incorrectly.

```pascal
[Code]
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
var Path : string;
begin
  Path := GetEnv('srcexe');
  SaveStringToFile('C:\appname\filename.txt',Path, False);
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`srcexe`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=srcexe) is not an *"environmental variable"*, it's an [Inno Setup constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).

To expand the constant, use the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant) with a proper constant syntax (curly brackets).

```pascal
Path := ExpandConstant('{srcexe}');
```